# Way for Authorizing Cognito access token in AWS Load Balancer prior to forwarding to api resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using **AWS ALB** and **Congnito service** to do Authorization for my apis.So using AWS Cognito service I can get access token by providing user credentials.

By using received access token I want to access api. So I need to **authorize that token** whether it is valid or not.

Is there way I can configure Cognito in ALB for Authorizer so that Cognito service will do Authorization for me just like it does Authentication to give access token.

Is there way I can define basic listener rules in ALB for **Cognito Authorization**. I know that we can add ALB listener rule for `Cognito Authentication`.

Comment: Any luck configuring ALB/Cognito for token authorization? Tried doing the same but got _The authorization code grant OAuth flow must be enabled in the user pool client_ error. My client is using Client credentials flow to support machine-to-machine communication.

Comment: @geca AWS ALB dont support Authorization part. You need to use API-Gateway, It will do Cognito Authorization on behalf of you.I started using API-Gateway along with AWS NLB.